# Solving the recurrence T(n) = T(n / 2) + O(1) using the Master Theorem?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, big-o, recurrence, master-theorem

I'm trying to solve a recurrence relation to find out the complexity of an algorithm using the Master Theorem and its recurrences concepts, how can I prove that:

> `T(n) = T(n/2)+O(1)`

is

> `T(n) = O(log(n)) ?`

Any explanation would be apprecciated!!

Comment: [Master theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem). Case 2. a = 1 and b = 2.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your recurrence is

> T(n) = T(n / 2) + O(1)

Since the Master Theorem works with recurrences of the form

> T(n) = aT(n / b) + n<sup>c</sup>

In this case you have

- a = 1
- b = 2
- c = 0

Since c = log<sub>b</sub>a (since 0 = log<sub>2</sub> 1), you are in [case two](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)#Case_2_example) of the Master Theorem, which solves to Θ(n<sup>c</sup> log n) = Θ(n<sup>0</sup> log n) = Θ(log n).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!!